how to grant access IAM roles manually Dataplex attribute store on entities from bigquery
error:
Updating IAM policy via Dataplex not supported for the resource associated with entity of name: projects/dataplex-experience-6133/locations/us-central1/lakes/lake-1/zones/zona-1/entities/second_table, type: TABLE, Storage system: BIGQUERY
What I've already done:
I went to BigQuery -> sharing -> permissions and added gcp-sa-dataplex
What I didn't achieve:
I didn't find the IAM path in Dataplex to create the custom role called "Dataplex Metadata Admin". Dataplex -> IAM & Admin -> Roles
does not exist.
I tried to add this roles manually via IAM but I didn't find entities.*Metadata by searching for roles via IAM -> role
Dataplex -> IAM & Admin -> Roles.

dataplex.entities.updateMetadata
dataplex.entities.getMetadata
dataplex.entities.list (if you want to allow listing entities)

I also tried to add the commands below through cloud shell, but I was unsuccessful, I still keep getting the error.
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [PROJECT-ID] 
--member="serviceAccount:service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@gcp-sa-dataplex.iam.gserviceaccount.com" 
--role="roles/bigquery.dataOwner"
My question originates from this thread:
https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/Dataplex-attribute-store-on-entities-from-bigquery/m-p/739311
